# Graph API not returning total_video_views

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

Tried the following endpoints:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{video-id}/video_insights/total_video_views?access_token={token}

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{video-id}/video_insights?access_token={token-id}&metric=total_video_views
```

But I still getting no data results in both endpoints:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

And my videos has some views (visualizações):

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna paste the words from the API documentation below, but I think, since it's a video, you're calling to the wrong site.

"Host URL
Almost all requests are passed to the graph.facebook.com host URL. The single exception is video uploads, which use graph-video.facebook.com."

And here's a link to the page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/#structure

Comment: Hi, tried using the URL graph-video.facebook.com but the return still the same.

Comment: Nuts.  Thanks for letting me know how it turned out.  Hopefully, the token/page token guy has the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem it's because you don't use the token from the page the video was published.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{video-id}/video_insights/total_video_views
```

Comment: Hi, without token, returns me the error: {
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "XXXXX"
   }
}

Comment: There is a difference between a token and a Page Token !